# How to resize programmatically ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, view, android-viewpager

I have in my layout a ViewPager which I would like to update the height programmatically with the height of my keyboard.

I've already tried to change the height with LayoutParams but there is not effect.

I've tried with the code below:

```
fun onKeyboardHeightChanged(keyboardHeight: Int) {
   if (keyboardHeight > 0) {
      view_pager?.let {
         val params = it.layoutParams
         params.height = keyboardHeight
         it.layoutParams = params
      }
   }
}
```

I've also tried with `requestLayout()`  on the ViewPager but not effect either.

Thank you for your answers and your help.

**EDIT:**

I've also tried to resize another view than the viewpager and it doesn't work either.
It seems the only time I can resize views is in `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`

***EDIT 2:***

I've found the source of all my problems: functions `showKeyboard()`and `hideKeyboard()` which are called in my fragment. When I call these functions, I can't edit the layout of my fragment and his component.

Above code for these functions:

**Hide Keyboard**

```
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = context?.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
    view?.let {
        imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(it.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

**Show Keyboard**

```
fun Fragment.showKeyboard() {
    val imm = context?.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
    imm?.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
}
```

Comment: try   val params = it.layoutParams as ParentLAYOUT.LayoutParams

Comment: No it's doesn't work either...

Comment: when is this method "onKeyboard.." being called, who calls it, and how does it know when to call it?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I found this method thanks to this solution : github.com/siebeprojects/samples-keyboardheigh

Comment: The URL doesn't work. :/

Comment: github.com/siebeprojects/samples-keyboardheight Sorry, a letter has been forgotten when copy paste