# RecyclerView doesn't update his item's layouts

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a RecyclerView which contains TextViews as items. When I click on a item, it selects him and it normally changes layout of the TextView.

However, TextView's layout doesn't update except if I scroll the RecyclerView. In back the item is selected, but in front, I have to scroll the RecyclerView to see the change.

For information, my RecyclerView is in a Fragment which is in a ViewPager2.

I use `notifyItemChanged()`and I tried with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I've also tried with `requestLayout()`and `invalidate()` on the RecyclerView and Parent's layout.

**EDIT 2 :**

I've found the source of my problems, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427212/how-to-resize-programmatically-viewpager) to check out.

Comment: Could you post your code as it is now? It would be helpful to see any data classes, or your adapter.

Comment: Try to debug this line  isSelected = position == selectedPosition .

Comment: This expression return the good result, but this line, and more exactly the function ```onBindViewHolder()```, has called only when I scroll Recycler or change page of ViewPager2

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about my poor English ! Is it works on Android5.1 or Android6.0,I have the same problem .finally I find a solution

**1. add a ListView(you can set the height or width to zero make it invisiable) to the Fragment where RecyleView in**

**2. set a Adapter to ListView**

then the RecyclerView in this fragment can notifyDataSetChanged() correctly ,even the RecyclerView in other fragment of the same ViewPager2 can work correctly, I don't know how it works ,but it works for me ,hope it works for you too